# Symfony 6.3 Email Validation The "loose" mode is deprecated

Tags: symfony

After upgrading Symfony from version 5.4 to 6.3. I encountered the following deprecation notice while running test cases

```
since symfony/validator 6.2: The "loose" mode is deprecated. It will be removed in 7.0 and the default mode will be changed to "html5".
```

How can we resolve this depreciation notice?

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was using the

```
Validation::createValidator()
```

This will ignore the package config. As described in this [issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/48541).

It was resolved by using

```
Validation::createValidatorBuilder()
        ->setConstraintValidatorFactory(new ConstraintValidatorFactory([EmailValidator::class => new EmailValidator(Assert\Email::VALIDATION_MODE_HTML5)]))
        ->getValidator()
```

As made possible by this [pull request](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/48644)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue after adding the following configuration in the file config/packages/framework.yaml

```
framework:
    validation:
        email_validation_mode: html5
```

Comment: Changing this option in `framework.yml` helped in my case.